# how can I make a function to save dataframe

Tags: r

I want to make a function to save dataframe, so I coded as below:

```
 save<-function(x)
{
write.table(x, file=paste(x,"csv", sep="."))
write.table(x, file=paste(x,"txt", sep="."))
}
```

but I got errors:

```
 save(summary1)
```

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
>   invalid 'description' argument
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filename is not a character string, it looks like your filename is an attempt to paste an entire dataframe as a string along with 'csv' (the `paste(x, 'csv', ...)`. This is because `x` is a dataframe, not a string, so R is complaining because it is not sure how to convert an entire dataframe to a single string.

If you want to save the file as 'x.csv' just do `file="x.csv"`.

If you want the user to be able to specify the filename you could do:

```
 save<-function(x, fname)
{
write.table(x, file=paste(fname,"csv", sep="."))
write.table(x, file=paste(fname,"txt", sep="."))
}
save(summary1, "summary") # saved as summary.csv
```